# Add bolts in a running topology of storm

Tags: apache-storm

I deploy a storm cluster with version 1.0.2. There is a case as below:
A topology is created and is submitted on the cluster to do some analysis for one client/customer. When another client  also needs the same analysis, as I think, the similar bolts can be created and append the spout in the topology. I wonder if it's possible to create such bolts when the topology is running. That means the running analysis for the first client can't be interrupted. Is it possible?

Thanks for your any comments.
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altering a running topology is not possible. You need to kill the topology and re-submit it with the newly added bolt.

Comment: Got it. I will change my design for the case. Thanks.